# Bootstrap coverage in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I would estimate the coverage of the bootstrap interval for the mean knowing that the true average is `895.0385`.
I have my vector `b<-c(300,300,200,250,600...)` and I make bootstrap and output interval:

```
mean.fun <- function(dat, idx) mean(dat[idx], na.rm = TRUE)
boot.out <- boot(b, mean.fun, R=999)
boot.ci(boot.out)
```

But how I can replicate this in order to obtain the coverage probability (how many times it contained the true average)?

Comment: Look into the`?replicate` function.

Comment: B    <- 999
 muH0 <-895.0385
 N    <- 52
 DV<- sample2
sdH0 <- 1318.027
getM <- function(orgDV, idx) {
 bsM   <- mean(orgDV[idx]) 
 bsS2M <- (((N-1) / N) * var(orgDV[idx])) / N 
 c(bsM, bsS2M)
 }
 bOut <- boot(DV, statistic=getM, R=B)
 boots <- t(replicate(B, getM(DV, sample(seq(along=DV), replace=TRUE))))
  I can replicate the boot but for replicate boot.ci?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something a bit like this a bit ago.  I didn't use the boot command I used the sample command but this might help.  I also might be 100% wrong, I am not very good with R yet.

```
mean.fun <- function(dat, idx) mean(dat[idx], na.rm = TRUE)
bootoutput <- data.frame(
  bootoutput = replicate(10000, boot.ci(boot(b, mean.fun, R=999)))
)
```

Comment: Yeah, I misclciked that and by the time I saw I couldn't find a way to remove it via an edit. =/