# Bootstrap Confidence Intervals in R?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

How can I compute 95% bootstrap confidence intervals for T.hat by the basic bootstrap confidence interval and the studentised bootstrap interval?

```
failtimes<-c(3, 5, 7, 18, 43, 85, 91, 98, 100, 130, 230, 487)
T.hat=length(failtimes)/sum(failtimes)

#Bootstrap estimate of bias
B <- 999   
n <- length(failtimes)
T.b <- numeric(B)

for (b in 1:B) {
    y <- sample(failtimes, size = n, replace = TRUE)
    T.b[b] <- mean(y)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would look at the package `boot` (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf) -- in particular, the function `boot.ci` computes these for you.

Comment: @Jealie Ok thanks but what would the "boot.out" object be for my bootstrap? Not sure how to compute it?

Comment: see if this question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726315/bootstrap-coverage-in-r as it includes an example of boot.out